# #1046: No database selected in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with phpMyAdmin. When I click on any database on the left I get an error like:

```
SELECT tracking_active FROM.`pma_tracking` 
WHERE db_name =  'information_schema'
AND table_name =  'CHARACTER_SETS'
ORDER BY version DESC

MySQL zwrócił komunikat: Dokumentacja

#1046 - No database selected
```

I can see database's tables if I click on '+' sign next to a database name and choose it but then I can't click on any other tab on the top of the page - I am getting the same error.

What can I do to make it work?